# statistical test for an effect across groups, data are nested, not of normal distribution

Tags: nested, statistics

What is the best statistical test for an effect across groups when the data are nested but may not be of normal distribution? I get a highly significant effect using Kruskall Wallis test, but using it there is no account to that the data points are from several locations, each contributed for several years, and in every year the data were pulled into age groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can categorize the data by year, and change the data structure so that the data will be non-nested, making it easier to process. I agree that Kruskal-Wallis' test is a good choice of the cross-group effect test.